# Code editor area only in Geany in fullscreen mode

Tags: editor, fullscreen, geany

OK, I would like to keep Sidebar, Toolbar and Message Window active when working in **Geany**, in normal mode, but I would also like to hide all these elements when switching to **fullscreen mode**.

Is there any way to reduce fullscreen mode to just a code editor area?

I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing to fullscreen there is no hook to hide other widgets. But: View->Toggle All Additional Widgets should do the deal.

Comment: Better than clicking options one by one, but there is still Side Bar visible. There seems to be no simple solution for that... :/ Anyway - thanks!

Comment: Please report it to feature tracker or provide a patch ;)

Comment: Nice, idea, frlan! I've registered feature request #702 :)

Comment: As F11 is the shortcut to fullscreen I've set F12 to "Toggle All Additional Widgets" and F10 to "Show sidebar", so at any given moment I can get exactly what I need with one or two keystrokes. Thank you both for the inspiration!